# Error - Plesk 12.5.30

Tags: vps, plesk

i installed plesk with Putty Ssh but i have one big problem , when i login to plesk it redirect me to an error page , you can see the picture
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVyBp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the smb_roles table is empty on your server. Try to create backup of your plesk and smb_roles table and create default smb roles in database.

First, Crete the backup

```
mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa > /root/psa.sql
mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa smb_roles > /root/psa.smb_roles.sql
```

Than, Login your mysql prompt and try with the following command.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `smb_roles` VALUES (1,'Admin',1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO `smb_roles` VALUES (2,'WebMaster',0,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.21 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO `smb_roles` VALUES (3,'Application User',0,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO `smb_roles` VALUES (4,'Accountant',1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO `smb_roles` VALUES (5,'Mail User',0,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```